# Calling remove on an non existing record crashes program

Tags: c++, hashmap, logic, hashtable

After calling remove for a record that doesn't exist in the table, the program crashes...i am assuming a null value is being passed in that I am missing in a logical step somewhere.

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and learn how to use a debugger. A debugger is an essential tool in any programmers toolbox, and knowing how to use one is an essential skill even for hobbyist programmers.

Comment: If you have a reasonably recent compiler, it should warn you when you write `=` but were most likely to mean `==`. If it doesn't, consider upgrading it or looking in the documentation for how to enable more warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The crash is to be expected. You do not check for nullptr in find. You can easily verify this: execute find after you have created the hash table.

Comment: the nullptr check was indeed the problem. I have updated my question. After calling remove() now on a record that shouldnt be in the table, it also crashes.

Comment: This is a second question, you should ask a new question. In addition after removing the source code how do you think people will answer your question?